# Как отлавливать строку со сканера штрих-кодов?

Tags: c#, wpf, штрихкод

Есть сканер штрих-кодов **Winson WNL-5000g-USB**. Необходимо реализовать приложение на C#(WPF) в котором в список будет добавляться строки считанные сканером.

Я никогда такого не делал и не имею малейшего понятия как заставить свое приложение отлавливать сканер в нужный момент и показывать считанный штрих-код. Как отлавливать строку которую считывает сканер?

Comment: ну думаю должно быть что то типа api  и с ним работать

Comment: я вообще не в теме, просто загуглил [это](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehall/2006/01/27/usb-barcode-scanner-heres-my-code/)

Comment: Сканер штрих-кода обычно повторяет действия с клавиатуры. Если на штрихкоде написано 123, то при чтении такого штрихкода генерируется нажатие 123. В редких случаях нужно делить сканер отдельно, клаву отдельно. А ещё штрих-код может  быть нераспознан - тогда его нужно вводить с клавиатуры.

Comment: А если бы сканер позволял вводить функциональные клавиши - то можно бы было вообще `format c:` в штриховой код зашить)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто. Данный сканер определяется на компьютере как клавиатура.
Я разместил обычный TextBox, поставил в него указатель мышки и поднес к сканеру штрих-код. Тут же в TextBox'е появился расшифрованный штрих-код. После небольших манипуляций выяснил что после того как сканер сканирует штрих-код, он пишет данные в поле ввода где установлен указатель и автоматический нажимает клавишу "Enter". А дальше дело техники:

1. Наводим указатель на TextBox.
2. Сканируем штрих-код.
3. Добавляем в поле TextBox определение клавиши "Enter". Теперь после того как штрих-код был отсканирован, автоматический вызывается команда которая добавляет штрих-код в список.
4. Обновляем список и видим в нем наш штрих-код.

Answer (score 1):

Диплом в прошлом году писал и как раз использовал их в работе. У сканеров есть три типа подключения:

**RS-232**

Данные будут передаваться в последовательный порт в виде ASCII-символов. Смотрим как работать с COM портами.

**USB-COM (USB-RS)**

Два варианта: эмуляция RS-232 или передача в порт ASCII-символов (тут зависит от производителя).  Нужны будут дрова или api.

**USB (разрыв клавиатуры) или PS/2**

Просто имитирует нажатие клавиш на клавиатуре. Ставим фокус на форму ввода сканируем и код будет в строке. Обращу внимание, что результат может зависеть от раскладки клавиатуры.

Comment: Я уже нашел данную информацию, спасибо. У меня оказался сканер имитирующий нажатия клавиатуры.