# Как отличить ввод сканера QR-кода от ввода клавиатуры?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть окно, в котором есть текстовое поле. Пользователь может вводить, но может и не вводить данные в текстовое поле. Окно программы позволяет рисовать разлчные фигуры. В любое время могут быть нажаты такие клавишы как Tab и Enter. К компьютеру также подключен через USB-порт сканер QR-кода, который имитирует нажатие клавиш на клавиатуре. Также возможно использование сканеров другого типа, например, беспроводных сканеров. Код, считываемый сканером, будет использоваться для валидации данных. Каким образом можно отличить ввод сканера QR-кода от ввода клавиатуры? В интернете нашла информацию, что сканер вводит символы с гораздо более высокой скоростью, чм человек с клавиатуры. В моем случае промежуток между вводом символов сканером 118-121 мс. С другой стороны, если я просто буду стучать руками по клавиатуре, символы будут вводится быстрее. Для получения текста, введенного со сканера или клавиатуры, я использовала событие TextInput. Есть ли у кого-нибудь какие-нибудь идеи по этому поводу?

Comment: У вас же валидация данных по коду идет по определенному формату, ну например если это хеш, то определенной длинны и определенный набор символов? Сделайте перехват клавиатуры (только в форме или глобальный) и считывайте данные в буфер, если буфер заполняется за определенное время, то скидывайте его на валидацию данных.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Отличить никак нельзя, так как сканер имитирует работу клавиатуры. Посмотрите, возможно что ваш сканер может работать в другом режим. В другом вопросе я описывал различные режимы работы: [Как отлавливать строку со сканера штрих-кодов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908513/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%88%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2/908663#908663)

Либо как вариант, при подключении сканера указывать в программе его порт и слушать его.