# Определение ID мыши при нажатии ПКМ на ней

Tags: c#, мышь

Есть компьютер, к которому подключена компьютерная мышь и кольпоскоп. При нажатии кнопки на кольпоскопе происходит событие идентичное нажатию ПКМ (сам кольпоскоп на компьютере также определяется как компьютерная мышь). Пробовал библиотеку **globalmousekeyhook**. С её помощью получалось реагировать на любые нажатия ПКМ (у мыши и кольпоскопа), но нужно реагировать только на кольпоскоп. И способа вытащить ID устройства в этой библиотеке я не нашёл (может плохо искал). Какой библиотекой можно воспользоваться, чтобы отследить нажатие кнопки именно на кольпоскопе?

Comment: А зачем принципиально требуется не реагировать на мышь? Что в этом плохого?

Comment: @aepot отвечу за автора) Кольпоскоп подаёт сигнал, нажатие мыши, и тут не понято что было нажато, реально мышь или кольпоскоп что-то хочет, автору нужно порты слушать...

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev ничего не понял, видимо устал от новогодних уже и не соображаю.

Comment: Как и писал @AlexanderSemikashev нужно реагировать именно на нажатие кнопки на кольпоскопе. Спасибо за совет ниже буду пытаться копать в этом направлении.

Answer (score 1):

Это ситуация подобно проблеме сканеров штрих-кодов, которые имитирует нажатие клавиатуры [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912152/Как-отличить-ввод-сканера-qr-кода-от-ввода-клавиатуры/912155](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912152/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-qr-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B/912155)

Что можно сделать в вашей ситуации:

1. Изучить сам кольпоскоп на предмет возможности подключение его не как мыши, а как устройства другого типа.
2. Иначе слушайте порт, в который вы подключаете устройство. Мне кажется это самый простой способ.