# Как получить доступ к порту сканера QR-кода?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть подключенный через USB-порт сканер QR-кода. Естественно, что известны его vendor ID и product ID. Как, имея эти данные, распознать, какой порт слушать? Я опыталась использовать библиотеку LibUsbDotNet, но не смогла понять, как с ней работать. Информацию о подключенных клавиатурах я могу получить следующим образом, но совершенно не могу понять, что делать дальше.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                              new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                              "SELECT * FROM Win32_Keyboard");
            ManagementObjectCollection keyboards = searcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in keyboards)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Win32_Keyboard instance");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Availability: {0}", queryObj["Availability"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Caption: {0}", queryObj["Caption"]);
                Console.WriteLine("ConfigManagerErrorCode: {0}", queryObj["ConfigManagerErrorCode"]);
                Console.WriteLine("ConfigManagerUserConfig: {0}", queryObj["ConfigManagerUserConfig"]);
                Console.WriteLine("CreationClassName: {0}", queryObj["CreationClassName"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
                Console.WriteLine("DeviceID: {0}", queryObj["DeviceID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("ErrorCleared: {0}", queryObj["ErrorCleared"]);
                Console.WriteLine("ErrorDescription: {0}", queryObj["ErrorDescription"]);
                Console.WriteLine("InstallDate: {0}", queryObj["InstallDate"]);
                Console.WriteLine("IsLocked: {0}", queryObj["IsLocked"]);
                Console.WriteLine("LastErrorCode: {0}", queryObj["LastErrorCode"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Layout: {0}", queryObj["Layout"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine("NumberOfFunctionKeys: {0}", queryObj["NumberOfFunctionKeys"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Password: {0}", queryObj["Password"]);
                Console.WriteLine("PNPDeviceID: {0}", queryObj["PNPDeviceID"]);

                if (queryObj["PowerManagementCapabilities"] == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("PowerManagementCapabilities: {0}", queryObj["PowerManagementCapabilities"]);
                else
                {
                    UInt16[] arrPowerManagementCapabilities = (UInt16[])(queryObj["PowerManagementCapabilities"]);
                    foreach (UInt16 arrValue in arrPowerManagementCapabilities)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("PowerManagementCapabilities: {0}", arrValue);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("PowerManagementSupported: {0}", queryObj["PowerManagementSupported"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", queryObj["Status"]);
                Console.WriteLine("StatusInfo: {0}", queryObj["StatusInfo"]);
                Console.WriteLine("SystemCreationClassName: {0}", queryObj["SystemCreationClassName"]);
                Console.WriteLine("SystemName: {0}", queryObj["SystemName"]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: А вы это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/908653/222542 читали? Может у вас таким же образом будет работать.

Comment: @Bulson у человека другая проблема, которую она описала в другом вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912152/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-qr-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B/912155

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для сканеров, работающих в режиме эмуляции клавиатуры, единственный способ выделить ввод конкретного устройства - использование [Raw Input](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/raw-input).

Пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {        
        //обработчик сообщений для окна
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {

            if (msg == Keyboard.WM_INPUT)
            {
                RAWINPUT data;
                int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUT));
                Keyboard.GetRawInputData(lParam, Keyboard.RID_INPUT, out data, ref size,
                    Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)));

                if (data.Header.Type == Keyboard.RawInputType_Keyboard)
                {                   
                    //выведем нажатую клавишу
                    textbox.Text += "["+Keyboard.VKCodeToUnicode((uint)data.Keyboard.VirtualKey)+"]";                    

                    //выведем тип события
                    switch (data.Keyboard.Message)
                    {
                        case Keyboard.WM_KEYDOWN:
                            textbox.Text += " pressed";
                            break;
                        case Keyboard.WM_KEYUP:
                            textbox.Text += " released";
                            break;
                    }                    
                    textbox.Text += Environment.NewLine;

                    //выведем устройство-источник
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(500);
                    uint strsize = (uint)sb.Capacity * 2;
                    uint result = Keyboard.GetRawInputDeviceInfo(data.Header.Device, Keyboard.RIDI_DEVICENAME, sb, ref strsize);
                    textbox.Text += "Source device: "+sb.ToString();
                    textbox.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                    textbox.Text += Environment.NewLine;

                }                  
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonRegister_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //регистрируем обработчик сообщений
            WindowInteropHelper h = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(h.Handle);
            source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));

            //регистрируем окно в Raw Input
            RAWINPUTDEVICE[] rid = new RAWINPUTDEVICE[1];
            rid[0].UsagePage = Keyboard.HidPage_Generic;
            rid[0].Usage = Keyboard.HidUsage_Keyboard;
            rid[0].WindowHandle = h.Handle;

            bool res = Keyboard.RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, 1, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)));
            if (res == false) MessageBox.Show("RegisterRawInputDevices failed");
        }
    }

    // Вспомогательный класс для работы с клавиатурой
    public class Keyboard
    {
        public const uint VK_CAPITAL = 0x14;
        public const uint WM_INPUT = 0x00FF;
        public const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        public const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        public const uint RID_INPUT = 0x10000003;
        public const uint RIDI_DEVICENAME = 0x20000007;
        public const uint RawInputType_Keyboard = 1;
        public const ushort HidPage_Generic = 0x01;
        public const ushort HidUsage_Keyboard = 0x06;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern uint GetRawInputDeviceList
        (
            [In, Out] RAWINPUTDEVICELIST[] RawInputDeviceList,
            ref uint NumDevices,
            uint Size
        );

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern uint GetRawInputDeviceInfo(
            IntPtr hDevice,
            uint uiCommand,
            [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pData,
            ref uint pcbSize);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, uint uiCommand, out RAWINPUT pData, ref int pcbSize, int cbSizeHeader);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool RegisterRawInputDevices([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)]
        RAWINPUTDEVICE[] pRawInputDevices, int uiNumDevices, int cbSize);

        [DllImport("USER32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetKeyState(int vKey);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int ToUnicodeEx(
            uint wVirtKey,
            uint wScanCode,
            byte[] lpKeyState,
            [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pwszBuff,
            int cchBuff,
            uint wFlags,
            IntPtr dwhkl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern uint MapVirtualKey(
            uint uCode,
            uint uMapType);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint idThread);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        //преобразование кода клавиши в символы
        public static string VKCodeToUnicode(uint vkCode)
        {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

            byte[] keyboardState = new byte[255];

            short x;
            byte y;

            for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {
                if (i == VK_CAPITAL)
                {
                    x = GetKeyState(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    x = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
                }
                y = 0;
                if ((x & 0x8000) != 0) y = (byte)(y | 0x80);
                if ((x & 0x0001) != 0) y = (byte)(y | 0x01);
                keyboardState[i] = y;
            }

            ToUnicodeEx(vkCode, MapVirtualKey(vkCode, 0), keyboardState, buf, 5, 0,
                GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero)));
            return buf.ToString();
        }

    }

    // Структуры

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RAWINPUTDEVICELIST
    {
        public IntPtr hDevice;
        public uint Type;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RAWINPUTDEVICE
    {
        /// <summary>Top level collection Usage page for the raw input device.</summary>
        public ushort UsagePage;
        /// <summary>Top level collection Usage for the raw input device. </summary>
        public ushort Usage;
        /// <summary>Mode flag that specifies how to interpret the information provided by UsagePage and Usage.</summary>
        public uint Flags;
        /// <summary>Handle to the target device. If NULL, it follows the keyboard focus.</summary>
        public IntPtr WindowHandle;
    }  

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RAWINPUTHEADER
    {
        /// <summary>Type of device the input is coming from.</summary>
        public uint Type;
        /// <summary>Size of the packet of data.</summary>
        public int Size;
        /// <summary>Handle to the device sending the data.</summary>
        public IntPtr Device;
        /// <summary>wParam from the window message.</summary>
        public IntPtr wParam;
    }   


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RAWINPUTKEYBOARD
    {
        /// <summary>Scan code for key depression.</summary>
        public short MakeCode;
        /// <summary>Scan code information.</summary>
        public ushort Flags;
        /// <summary>Reserved.</summary>
        public short Reserved;
        /// <summary>Virtual key code.</summary>
        public ushort VirtualKey;
        /// <summary>Corresponding window message.</summary>
        public uint Message;
        /// <summary>Extra information.</summary>
        public int ExtraInformation;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct RAWINPUT
    {
        /// <summary>Header for the data.</summary>
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RAWINPUTHEADER Header;      

        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public RAWINPUTKEYBOARD Keyboard;        

    }    
}
```

Внимание: код заточен под 32-разрядные приложения.

Имя устройства в данном случае будет иметь вид `\\?\ACPI#PNP0303#0#{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}`. Вас интересует часть между `\\?\` и `{...}`, которая представляет собой слегка измененный Device Instance ID (PnpDeviceID в WMI).

Comment: Вы не могли бы пояснить функцию VKCodeToUnicode(uint vkCode)?

Comment: Например, почему размер keyboardState равен 255? Что такое public const uint VK_CAPITAL = 0x14? Что значат эти условия if ((x & 0x8000) != 0) y = (byte)(y | 0x80); и if ((x & 0x0001) != 0) y = (byte)(y | 0x01);?

Comment: @Liidia Это конвертация виртуального кода клавиши в символ с учетом текущей раскладки клавиатуры и состояния клавиш Shift и Caps Lock. Подробно это обсуждалось здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/getkeyboardstate-определение-состояния-клавиши . Массив KeyboardState имеет размер в 256 элементов по аналогии с функцией [GetKeyboardState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate). Условия - это проверка значения определенного бита в целочисленной переменной с помощью битовой маски.

Comment: VK_CAPITAL - виртуальный код клавиши Caps Lock. Константа из заголовочных файлов Windows SDK.

Comment: Спасибо! Поняла.

Comment: Сколько же все таки виртульных ключей? Если мы посмотрим сюда https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.VirtualKeys и сюда https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes, то их получается 254.

Comment: @Liidia 254 + два неиспользуемых (0 и 0xFF), всего 256.